# Meteor $and with $or

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I'm trying to do an $and and then $or in Meteor for my mongo query I have the following but it doesn't seem to be working

Would like the query to match documents where organizationId key has value in the variable user.organizationId AND where the type key is either 'converntional' or 'transition'

```
{
    organizationId: user.organizationId,  
    $and:[
       { $or:[
           {type: 'conventional'},
           {type: 'transition'}
       ]}
   ]
};
```

I can't use $not as I'm pretty sure it's not supported in Meteor. Right now the package I'm using does not support it.

Comment: `$and` essentially does nothing, because you only have a single clause following it. What's the result supposed to be, expressed in English?

Comment: I think you need [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) as follows `{organizationId:user.organizationId, type: { $in : ['conventional', 'transition'] }}`

Comment: @deceze give all X collections that match organizationId and have must have the type conventional or transition

Comment: @chridam I thought $in was just for arrays?

Comment: @chridam $in does not work

Comment: No, it matches documents where `type` is one of 2 possibilities that you define in the array.

Comment: Can you please describe the query condition in plain English? As far as I can see, you want the query to match documents where `organizationId` key has value in the variable `user.organizationId` **AND** where the `type` key is either `'converntional'` or `'transition'`, is that right? If so then `$in` is definitely what you need. Can you also provide a sample document from your MongoDB collection?

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain your logic like you were asked to in the beginning please. There is no explanation at all of what **$not** was supposed to do for you here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following query describes what you are after as it uses the **[`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)** operator to match documents where the type key is either `'converntional'` or `'transition'`. The **[`$and`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/)** operator is implicitly provided when specifying a comma separated list of expressions. Using an explicit AND with the **[`$and`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/)** operator is only necessary when the same field or operator has to be specified in multiple expressions.

> Would like the query to match documents where organizationId key has
>   value in the variable user.organizationId AND where the type key is
>   either 'converntional' or 'transition'

```
{
    organizationId: user.organizationId, 
    type: { 
        $in : ['conventional', 'transition'] 
    }
}
```

Comment: $in was exactly what I was looking for, perfect, thanks.