# Looking for symbol to filter all

Tags: mongodb, meteor, minimongo

Is there a search all filter when trying to search through the db?  I have multiple select boxes that I would like to get the value of and then according to the values, it searches for the data.  I found that I would need to have an if statement for each select box to check if it is the default value(String) or a selected value(Integer).

```
items.find({
        "person.age": obj.age, //is 'All'
        "person.gender": obj.gender // is 'male'
      },{
        limit: this.state.limit
      }).fetch()
```

In my example above, one is the default (all) and the other is the selected value.  When I try to search, it would return nothing because of the 'all'.  I am looking for a symbol or something to replace the 'all'.

Comment: are you looking for something like $or operator?

Comment: How about get all of the select values, "filter out" the ones with the default ("all") values that do not constrain the query, and build a query filter from the remaining values?

Comment: I believe your desired solution is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30935591/meteor-and-with-or

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@masteram is right - you want to avoid the keys that contain `All` - there is no `*` in mongodb. You can simplify your logic at the same time.

The following will copy only the keys of `obj` that are not equal to `All` then run the search on those keys:

```
const person = {};
Object.keys(obj).forEach((k) => {
  if (obj[k] !== 'All') person[k] = obj[k];
});

items.find(person, { limit: this.state.limit }).fetch()
```